# Separating database by attribute using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to separate a database by year using a loop in R, however I´m having troubles when trying to save my multiple results. My code is this one

```
d<- read.csv("BD_070218.csv")

results<-NULL
for(i in 1990:2015){
  ano<-d[which(d$year==i),]
  results[[i]] <- ano

}
```

Comment: I think you need `split(d, d$year)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question.
Two potential methods.

```
# Set a seed
set.seed(1)

# Create example dataframe
d <- data.frame(
    a=1:120,
    year=sample(1990:2015,120,replace = TRUE),
    d=sample(letters,120,replace = TRUE)
    )

# Method 1: Nested dataframes in a list
results<-list()
for(i in 1990:2015){
  ano<-d[which(d$year==i),]
  eval(parse(text=paste("results$year_",  i, " <- ano",  sep="")))
}
str(results)
results[["year_2012"]]

# Method 2: individual dataframes
for(i in 1990:2015){
  ano<-d[which(d$year==i),]
  assign(paste0("year_",i), ano, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
str(year_2000)
```